# Check if one of multiple attributes contains some value for every object in a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is the code:

```
querySet = dataModel.objects.all()
#assume the existance of a valid data model 'dataModel', assume it has a valid attribute 'attribute'

if all(object.attribute == '3' or object.attribute == '4' or object.attribute == '5' for object in querySet):
    #Do something
else:
    #Do somthing else
```

When I load the webpage, I get the following:

```
Exception Value: global name 'all' is not defined
```

Additional information:

Django Version: 1.3.1

I am trying to check if every object in the `queryset` has an attribute value of 3,4 or 5. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: what about using `filter`? Also I don't think thast the way `all` works, `all` takes an iterable and checks that each member is truthy

Comment: there are filters in the real code but i cannot display the code here for privacy issues. that should not make a difference to the question being asked. if it does, please elaborate. thanks

Comment: so what how exactly would you fix this? I am trying to check if every object in the queryset has an attribute value of 3,4 or 5

Answer (score 3):

The error is, [`all` expects an iterable as a parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), and it gets something else.

Try this:

```
if all([object for object in querySet if object.attribute == '3' or object.attribute == '4' or object.attribute == '5' ]):
    #Do something
```

In my opinion, however - this is the *wrong* usage of `all()`

Consider using:

```
querySet = dataModel.objects.filter(attribute__in=[3, 4, 5])
```

and

```
if queryset.count():
    #do something
```

Comment: the 'try this' suggestion outputs the same error. i can investigate your second suggestion however what does 'if queryset.count():' mean? Does it mean "if there are objects that have an attribute value of 3,4, or 5 do something"?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax !

Try something like:

```
if dataModel.objects.exclude(attribute__in=[3,4,5]).exists():
  # we have objects in queryset that have attribute different than 3,4,5
else:
  # all objects have attribute equal to 3,4 or 5
```